# What is the correct data type for JpaRepository that has Primary Key but it is also a Foreign Key?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following tables,

```
User
int id PK

Contact
int id PK, FK to User.id
```

So my code in `Contact.java` is as follows,

```
@Getter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
@Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
@Id
@Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
private User userId;
```

In my `User.java` it has,

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

So according to the above code, I have some questions.

1. Is that the correct approach to indicate that id(primary key) of Contact is also a foreign key to User?
2. And do I need to use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` or `@JoinColumn`?
3. According to the above code how my repository interface should be?

   ```
    public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, User> {}
   ```

   or

   ```
    public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Integer> {}
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use foreign key as primary key, if use can
2. JoinColumn
3. Contract has Integer id, so `<Contact, Integer>`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for your time.